# How to calculate the x,y-tile-coordinates from lat,long if given images in EPSG25832-projection method?

Tags: xml, ros, map-projections, utm, mercator

I have a question regarding the creation of the WMTS server requests and with that the calculation of the tile number.

From [this](https://www.bezreg-koeln.nrw.de/brk_internet/geobasis/luftbilderzeugnisse/digitale_orthophotos/index.html) german governmental-website I can get the address for their WMTS server: https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop. I can successfully integrate it into josm as an image layer (wmts:https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop) and it gets displayed correctly.

I can watch the server request made by josm in the terminal, which is something like:`2019-09-26 18:54:31.651 INFO: GET https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_25832_16/16/17680/35107 -> HTTP_1 200 (13.3 kB)`
You can view this tile image: https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_25832_16/16/17680/35107

In this [rviz-plugin](https://github.com/gareth-cross/rviz_satellite) I entered the string for the request: `https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_25832_16/{z}/{y}/{x}`

If I let rviz_satellite figure out the y and x, I'm getting trash in rviz:
[image: img]

I think this is because the images/tiles are in EPSG25832-projection method, but rviz-satellite thinks in Mercator-projection. And I need the images to be in EPSG25832, because of other data which gets displayed.

If you look at the WMTSCapabilities.xml of the map-server you can see there are images available up to zoom level 16 and other info: https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_25832_16/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

I had a look at [the methods, which the rviz-satellite seems to use to calculate the x and y](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_tile_numbers), which is something like this:

```
// in Coordinates.h:
int const n = 1 << zoom;
double x = n * ((coord.lon + 180) / 360.0);
double y = n * (1 - (std::log(std::tan(lat_rad) + 1 / std::cos(lat_rad)) / M_PI)) / 2;
```

But I think I need to do something like this, because of the EPSG25832/UTM projection:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection

I already had a look at https://josm.openstreetmap.de/doc/org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/Tile.htm to see how openstreetmap does it, but I didn't find anything.

**So all in all: How to calculate the x,y-tile-coordinates from lat,long if given images in EPSG25832-projection method (which josm/osm does succesfully)?**

Answer (score 0):

For your URL pattern: `https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_25832_16/{z}/{y}/{x}` you've swapped the `x` and `y` parameters. You can also just use `EPSG_3857_16` and not worry about re-projecting the tiles (per the linked XML).

What you probably want is (untested): `https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop/tiles/nw_dop/EPSG_3857_16/{z}/{x}/{y}`